# PermissonDeniedError tensorboard --logdir=${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to run a test training simulation for TF object detection (open sourced by google). I am following the steps as mentioned.
https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine

my training and evulation command is perfectly running fine. I can see the model checkpoint in the dir. I am running training simulation on google cloud.

And checking the status from my local machine (mac).
When i ran the 
tensorboard --logdir=${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}

I get following error.

Can someone would help me to point the error.
It seems some dir. permission issue. but i am not able to understand where should i modify it in the code. It is pointing to the root dir to write something. How to i change something that would make the tensorboard, not writing into the / root dir.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 327, in _reload_forever
    reload_multiplexer(multiplexer, path_to_run)
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 299, in reload_multiplexer
    multiplexer.AddRunsFromDirectory(path, name)
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/plugin_event_multiplexer.py", line 175, in AddRunsFromDirectory
    for subdir in GetLogdirSubdirectories(path):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/plugin_event_multiplexer.py", line 445, in <genexpr>
    subdir
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/io_wrapper.py", line 50, in ListRecursively
    for dir_path, _, filenames in tf.gfile.Walk(top):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 514, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 495, in walk
    listing = list_directory(top)
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 474, in list_directory
    compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/jalajjain/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /.DocumentRevisions-V100/.cs/ChunkStorage/0/0/1**
```

Comment: This looks strange: you show a **python** stacktrace, but then you have `logdir=${..}` - that very much looks like a **shell** script, or maybe perl ... but not like python. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to authenticate your local machine with the Google Cloud SDK. The document you linked to suggests doing: `gcloud auth application-default login`.